# C# equivalent to Objective-C's dispatch_group and queue?

Tags: c#, objective-c, multithreading

I'm in the process of porting an Objective-C app over to C# and I'm struggling to achieve the following functionality in C#

```
// create a new dispatch group
dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    // iterate over a collection adding blocks to the dispatchQueue identified by dispatchGroup
    dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatchQueue, ^{
        // do stuff
    });
}

// wait for them all to finish
dispatch_group_wait(dispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// do more stuff that depends on them all finishing
```

How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: See [System.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) along with the C# [async/await feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This requires at least version 4.5 of the .NET Framework.

```
// create a new dispatch group
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

// iterate over a collection adding tasks to the dispatch group
for (…) {
    Task task = Task.Run(() => {
        // do stuff
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

// wait for them all to finish
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

// do more stuff that depends on them all finishing
```